# Does any theme support child theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I'm trying to add some new functionalities to a theme and I'm using [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) as should be. So the theme is called `u-design` and I created a folder called `u-design-child`. Inside the folder I've created two files: `style.css` and `functions.php`. This is the content for each one so far:

```
// style.css
/*
Theme Name: U-Design Child
Theme URI: http://localhost
Description: Child theme for U-Design.
Author: Reynier
Author URI: http://localhost
Version: 1
License: Located in 'licensing' folder
License URI: Located in 'licensing' folder
*/

// functions.php 
<?php
// Add Shortcode for Random Phrases
function random_phrase()
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'frase',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby'        => 'rand'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Build output string
    $quo = '';
    $quo .= $query->post->post_title;
    $quo .= ' said "';
    $quo .= $query->post->post_content;
    $quo .= '"';

    return $quo;
}

add_shortcode('phrase', 'random_phrase');
```

But when I go to `Appearance > Themes` and try to enable the child theme I see this:

> The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a stylesheet and a template.

What I've missed here? Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `Template:` definition in your stylesheet header. This is the folder name of the parent theme

For instance, a child theme of the bundled theme will have the `Template:` defined as

```
Template: twentyfifteen
```

Comment: Thx, that fixes my problem